# Postgresql table update problem with Python?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, algorithm

I have a table that I created using Postgresql in Python. This table has 3 columns (id, fruit, color). The id value is **"id = Column(Integer(), Primary_key=True)"** in the code and is randomly assigned by the database. I want to write code in Python that satisfies the following conditions, can you help me?

1. If the name apple is not included in the new data when the code is run, delete the apple row in the database.
2. If the new data is pear value when the code is run and there is no pear value in the database, add the pear value to the database.
3. If the new incoming data contains a lemon when the code is run and there is already a lemon variable in the database, update it if the color of the lemon is different, otherwise do not change it.

| id | fruit | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | red |
| 3 | lemon | yellow |

The methods I tried deleted the data from the database.

Comment: 1) Where is `id = Column(Integer(), Primary_key=True)` coming from? It is not a SQL definition of a column, so is it coming from an ORM or is home-built? 2) Show the code you attempted. *Add as text update to question**. 3) Your 3) could possibly be handled by [On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).

Comment: The easiest thing to do is create a temporary table, insert into that, index `fruit`, delete from the original table where not in the temporary table, then do an upsert using `insert...on conflict`. The main problem with this is that your ORM is unlikely to directly support any of these features.

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy?  Given the existing dataset above, if the new data did not include an apple, would you want to delete the first row?  As @AdrianKlaver said, please include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using SQLAlchemy. The id is assigned automatically when writing data to the database. I solved the problem. I am sharing the code.

```
def db_process(self):
    
    req_data = self.get_fruits()    
    db_data = session.query(FruitModel).all()

    for data in req_data :
        db_data_filter = session.query(FruitModel).filter_by(fruit=data[0]).first()  

        if not db_data_filter:
            session.add(FruitModel(*data))
        else:
            db_data_filter.color = data[1]
              
    for db_data_entry in db_data:
        if (db_data_entry.fruit, db_data_entry.color) not in req_data:
            session.delete(db_data_entry)    

    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

Comment: Great that you solved the problem.  Could you describe what you changed that helped you get to the solution in case that helps other people?